# Set bucket Django google storage in view

Tags: django, google-cloud-storage

I have a view that is storing data in GoogleStorage. I have different buckets for different projects - so I cant use `settings.GS_BUCKET_NAME`. How I can set dynamically GS bucket name?

I have following idea, but no idea if it will work

```
class GStogare(GoogleCloudStorage):
    bucket_name = ""

    def set_bucket_name(self, somethig_with_bucket_name_id):
        self.bucket_name = SomethingWithBucketName.objects.\
                           get(pk=something_with_bucket_name_id).bucket

gstogare = GStorage()
class FileModel(models.Model):
    something_with_bucket_name = models.ForeighKey(....)
    file = models.FileField(storage=gstorage)

    def save(self, gstorage, force_insert=False, force_update=False, using=None,
             update_fields=None):
        gstorage.get_bucket_name(self.somethig_with_bucket_name)
        super().save(force_insert=False, force_update=False, using=None,
                     update_fields=None)
```

Basically - override `GoogleCloudStorage` class, make it set bucket_name dynamically in model save method. Could it work?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the [Google Cloud Storage API](https://googleapis.github.io/google-cloud-python/latest/storage/client.html)?
On that doc you can find some useful examples and usages.

For instance, with the `bucket()` method you call a Bucket instance by their name, it returns a [Bucket object](https://googleapis.github.io/google-cloud-python/latest/storage/buckets.html#module-google.cloud.storage.bucket) with its own methods to interact with (create a signed upload policy for uploading objects, delete the bucket, set lifestyle rules, list files, etc).

Try it so you won't have to override the `GoogleCloudStorage` class.

Comment: How is that supposed to help?